Can I Programmatically Set the "Related Video" for YouTube Shorts Using YouTube Data API?
I'm uploading a full-length YouTube video and a related YouTube Short using the YouTube Data API in Python. In YouTube Studio, there's an option when editing a Short to set a "Related video", which directs viewers to related content.
My Question:

Is there a way to set the "Related video" for a YouTube Short via the YouTube Data API?
If not, are there any workarounds to achieve this programmatically?

Any guidance on how to set the "Related video" programmatically would be greatly appreciated!
